# gdal_calc.py SyntaxError

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdal-calc

I tried to use `gdal_calc.py` to avoid using the manual GUI raster calculator in QGIS. However, I'm not yet familiar with it and having errors with my code:

```
gdal_calc.py -A perennials.tif -B annuals.tif --outfile=annuals_only.tif --calc="(A<=85 or B=2001)*(A)" --format=GTiff 0 .. evaluation of calculation (A<=85 or B=2001)*(A) 

evaluation of calculation (A<=85 or B=2001)*(A) failed Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_calc.py", line 401, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_calc.py", line 394, in main
    doit(opts, args)
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_calc.py", line 288, in doit
    myResult = eval(opts.calc, global_namespace, local_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 1
    (A<=85 or B=2001)*(A)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there some thing I can improve in my --calc formula?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong for logical operator (or). Try this:

```
gdal_calc.py -A perennials.tif -B annuals.tif --outfile=annuals_only.tif --calc="A*logical_or(A<=85, B=2001)"
```

I would also add `--NoDataValue=0` to avoid large black areas in the output.

Comment: Hello, I'm having these errors:
0 .. evaluation of calculation A*logical_or(A<=85, B=2001) failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_calc.py", line 401, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_calc.py", line 394, in main
    doit(opts, args)
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_calc.py", line 288, in doit
    myResult = eval(opts.calc, global_namespace, local_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid number of arguments

Comment: Please remove the extra characters at the end of your original command or copy/paste the command from my answer.

Comment: Hello, I did your suggestion. I'm thinking, is it possible that I have problems with numpy? Installed it recently and nothing happens.

Comment: Try to start Python and import numpy manually. Do you use Windows or Linux?

Comment: I use Linux. Yes I'll try doing it manually.